# Beamer color undefined in Xcolor package

Tags: beamer, color

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\usepackage[EU2]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage[default,scale=1]{opensans}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\tdb}[1]{\textcolor{DarkBlue}{#1}} % text DarkBlue

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\begin{frame}{}
 \begin{block}{}
   \begin{Huge}
     \tdb{Section Title}
   \end{Huge}
 \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### Error

Although `svgnames option` shows `DarkBlue` I get:

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `DarkBlue'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.25 \end{frame}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well you are not using the svgnames option. I removed all packages not needed or wrong with a current lualatex.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage[default,scale=1]{opensans}

\newcommand{\tdb}[1]{\textcolor{DarkBlue}{#1}} % text DarkBlue

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\begin{frame}{}
 \begin{block}{}
   \begin{Huge}
     \tdb{Section Title}
   \end{Huge}
 \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So `xcolor` package is already loaded by beamer and I have only to specify the option?

Comment: Hm, I thing that `Huge` is not an environment but switch from some (used) font size to `\Huge` size. Therefore it should be `\begin{block}{} \Huge \tdb{Section Title} \end{block}`.